# Progress towards team goals '50 questions' and '75 answers' is off

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

We have 141 questions so far in our Team, but the progress bar on the right suggests we're closer to 48:

[image]

Now that I look at it again, the number of answers is also off. We have 127 questions with at least one answer, certainly not less than 75.

Comment: Just delete 91 questions to meet the goal?

Comment: Could try, but I don't have d̶i̶a̶m̶o̶n̶d̶ hexagon powers there.

Comment: Is it 50 questions *with* answers? If not, I blame *caching*! :)

Comment: @Paulie_D it's been like this for at least 6-8 days, and 127 of those 141 questions have an answer.

Comment: Accepted answers? Just guessing here!

Comment: 78 questions with accepted answers.

Comment: ..then caching or perhaps the script runs infrequently. :) <shrug/>

Comment: @Paulie_D yup, definitely a caching bug. This cache has a TTL of 1 day, but the charcoal team was created before we added a TTL. We're currently working on clearing this cache.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That explains why the Moderator Team is not affected.

Comment: @Glorfindel is the goals checklist showing the correct counts now?

Comment: @jisoo yes, thanks a lot for fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jisoo:

> yup, definitely a caching bug. This cache has a TTL of 1 day, but the
>   charcoal team was created before we added a TTL. We're currently
>   working on clearing this cache.
>
> is the goals checklist showing the correct counts now?

Glorfindel:

> yes, thanks a lot for fixing it.